# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Kindly bear with me. I am a Microsoft SQL Server person with loads of Visual Studio experience, but I need to get something done using a MySQL database.

I am trying to create a little tool here that will allow our developers to quickly update database records, and I am using Visual Studio to create a small Windows Form to do this.

In a [Microsoft SQL Server connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), I could write something like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=username;Password=password;
```

In a [MySQL connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), there appear to be multiple other options, but the first one looks basically the same:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

When I attempt to open the MySQL connection from my PC, I get the exception listed in the title (actually, it shows the Uid value and the IP Address of my PC instead of `localhost`, but I am hoping more people will recognize the error easier this way):

```
public static void MySQLi_Connect() {
  m_err = null;
  var str = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr;
  try {
    m_conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr);
    m_conn.Open();
  } catch (MySqlException err) {
    ErrorLog("MySQLi_Connect", err);
  }
}
```

I did a search, and it seems that the `Uid` on MySQL needs to be granted access from the specific IP Address that the connection is being made from.

Further, I found this on the [mysql.com doc pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html):

> If you do not know the IP address or host name of the machine from which you are connecting, you should put a row with '%' as the Host column value in the user table. After trying to connect from the client machine, use a SELECT USER() query to see how you really did connect. Then change the '%' in the user table row to the actual host name that shows up in the log. Otherwise, your system is left insecure because it permits connections from any host for the given user name.

A few things:

- It looks like I can connect to MySQL by using a `%` setting in the **Uid** `jp2code`, but MySQL says I need to change that back right away to remove system vulnerability.
- Microsoft SQL Server did not seem to require this - or, if it did, I simply never was slapped in the face with this vulnerability issue like MySQL is doing.

### Now, I ask:

- If this is going to be a tool used by different developers on different PCs, is it common practice to turn the blind eye to this horrendous *system vulnerability*?
- Is this not really as big of a concern as MySQL is making it appear?
- What is the best way to continue with a Windows Forms application that needs to connect from various locations? Obviously, I do not want to continuously be adding more entries for a particular application every time another developer wants to use the tool or someone tries to run it from a different PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the security of your MySQL server as strong as you like, usually you dont connect users but applications. So if you have your root user without password in production environment is your fault. Usually developers have access to development environment, so this is not a big deal.

Of course try to have as many users as roles you need, for your example I think one user is enough. In production use a secure config file for save a secure password and set you mysqlserver restricted.

Comment: So, if an application were being built for a thumb drive, for example, there is not really any way for it to connect without exposing MySQL vulnerability.

Comment: Is there a way to narrow down the **wildcard** search to remain local (i.e. within the network)? I'm very new to PHP and MySQL, and I'm trying to test the limits of what I can or cannot do.

Comment: For portable applications usually the database is in the same machine, so you can restrict access to 127.0.0.1  and use strong user and password. You can deploy the entire engine in an usb because MySQL is very lite.

Comment: Hmmmm... no, we need to upload database files for our company's web server.

Comment: So, you need a thumb drive app that connect with a web server database?

Comment: No, I'd like a PC app that I and other developers can use to connect to our web server database without having to add entries for each particular PC.

Comment: Two options: 1) Use a strong user and password, change password usually, and set a wildcard for IP. 2) Add a VPN between PC's and WebServer and set the user available only for VPN range addresses connections. I dont know too much about SQL-SERVER but I Think that is not too different

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I found out that the password wasn't  correct.

GO to your sql command line and type the code below:
**mydb** in the line below is the name of the database  you are working on. 
**passwd** in the line has to match the password you have in c# code so in your     case "password"

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'passwd';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like OP says you can wildcard the hostname portion. I used this on our dev-server (not recommended for production servers):

```
update mysql.user set host = '%' where host='localhost';
```

Then I had to restart the server to make MySQL use it (propably I could just have restarted the MySQL service).